# GoogleMaps GeoPoint value range

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, geopoints

I tried to add some `GeoPoints` on my map but I've problems with some “special” points.

The range of the latitude value is +90 to -90 and therefore I want to add a point like the this...

```
int latitude: 85000000;
int longitude = 45000000;
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
```

...and after this I double check the latitude value with:

```
point.getLongitudeE6();
```

I always get a maximum value of 80000000 back. Can someone explain why google set this limit for a `GeoPoint` and what the reason for this limitation is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with `getLatitudeE6()`. `GeoPoint` doesn't work near the poles. You're probably going too far north or too far south.

This behavior is by design. From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/index?com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html):

> [The latitude] will be clamped to between -80 degrees and +80 degrees
>   inclusive, in order to maintain accuracy in the Mercator projection.

Likewise, longitude is limited to -180 to +180.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Do you know why google set up these limits?

Comment: Well the longitude limit (-180 to +180) is just the logical limit, since that covers the globe. The latitude limit is for accuracy, as they said, since lines of latitude get really close together at the poles. You'd probably want an azimuthal projection for work at the poles; Google Maps uses Mercator.